# RealmBaseAdapter not updating Listview when RealmResults is Updated

Tags: android, listview, realm

My Current Adapter Implementation is

```
 RealmResults<Contact> contacts = realmController.getContacts();
 contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ContactsActivity.this, contacts);
 contactsListView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
```

I have extended RealmBaseAdapter for contactAdapter for using with the listView

I also have a search Edit Text where the user will search for the contact .

```
    searchUser.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            contacts = realmController.searchContact(searchUser.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Here the contacts gets updated but the listview is not changing .

Did I miss anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to call `contactAdapter.updateData(contacts)` so that you actually replace the results inside your adapter.

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        contacts = realmController.searchContact(searchUser.getText().toString());
        contactAdapter.updateData(contacts);
    }
```